# firefox adding white border to rendered image

Tags: css, firefox

Firefox is adding a white border on the inside of my image (.png), but no other browsers is, and the `border` property in CSS is actually 0. It's the image itself that is being rendered with a white border... Any way to remove this?

Comment: Assuming this is a plain Browser specific styling issue . Check https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: can you create fiddle for same issue

Comment: Firefox is my regular browser in all the platforms I use (Windows Desktop and Android) and I can assure you that it doesn't add white borders to pictures in a regular basis. You must have custom code in your site that accomplish it.

Comment: Are you using anchor tag to image? pls provide code?

Comment: It's got a `max-height` CSS property, set to 10vw. If I take that off, the white lines go away... Why would adding a `max-height` create a white outline in Firefox?

Comment: The C is CSS stands for cascading. Styles are not the result of a single rule. If you need help you really have to post some real code that reproduces the issue (and I'd also suggest you give Developer Tools a try.)

Comment: I am fully aware of this, and I have used the developer tools to confirm that there is no styling property that is causing this issue. I unselected every rule, except `max-height`, and then toggled the `max-height`. This is how I confirmed that for some reason using the rule `max-height` is creating this white outline

Comment: @A.Appleby - Sounds as though it could be an aspect ratio thing. How is the width calculated? Is it set to display: block; ?

Comment: Display is currently `inline-block`, but setting it to `display: block` does not change anything. The width is auto-calculated and the it's got `max-height: 10vw`

Answer (score 1):

Give it a class and set `display: block;`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I wanted a 110x90px image and for that I was using a 560x460px image

with these css rules

```
.my-image 
{ 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 110px; 
    height: 90px;
}
```

Turns out when i tried to use the same image **but** with the right dimensions it worked. White border was left on firefox.